# Is it possible to increase the length of text inside notification bar (Android)

Tags: java, android, cordova, push-notification

I added more content to my message but its not showing the entire thing. Is it possible to get full content of message in notification bar. Is this handle by client side, to increase the size limit of notification.

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().collapseKey("message").timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("msgcnt","3")
                .addData("message",(String) messageObj.get("Company")+":"+(String) messageObj.get("issues")+"-->"+(String) messageObj.get("Description")+" "+(String) messageObj.get("level")+" "+(String) messageObj.get("StartTime")+" "+(String) messageObj.get("nature"))
                .build();
```

Comment: No. It do have limits as google doesn't want one notification to be too big. Each notification has fixed height which can not override.

Comment: @OwenZhao Really its good info. Thanks for your immediate attention.

Comment: I think you would be able to display longer strings if the notification is expandable, i.e. used on Android 4.1 or 4.2 I can't remember which version introduced expandable notifications

Comment: I am using 4.2.2 Jelly beans still i am not getting expandable notifications.